# TCP Connect error 115 Operation in Progress What is the Cause?

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming, errno

My application creats a TCP connection, This is working normaly.
But in one network server has many IP  say

- 174.X.X.X
- 54.x.x.x
  like this

When calling TCP connect (Non blocking with timeout of 60 seconds) 
to IP `174.X.X.X`  is always success .
But TCP connect to same server with ip `54.x.x.x`  is failing (most of the times) with errno 115 
measn operation in progress.

Can you please explain me what are the possible reason for errno 115

OS : Linux

My TCP conenct code is as below

```
tcp_connect(......)
{

  int iValOpt = 0;  
  int iLength= 0;

  fcnt((int)(long)SockID,F_SETFL_O_NONBLOCK);

  ret = connect (sockID,(struct sockaddr*)pstSockAdr,uiSockLen);

  if (ret < 0)
  {

        if (errno == EINPROGRESS)
        {
                stTv.tv_sec = 60;
                stTv.tv_usec = 0;
                FD_ZERO(&write_fd);
                FD_SET(sockID,&write_fd);

                iLength = sizeof(int);

                if (0 < select (sockID+1) , NULL,&write_fd,NULL,&stTv);

                {
                        if(0 > getsockopt(sockID,SOL_SOCKET,SO_ERROR,(void*)(&iValOpt),&iLength))
                        {
                                return -1
                        }

                        if (0 != iValOpt)
                        {
                                return -1;
                        }


                        return success;
                }

                else
                {
                        return -1;
                }   

        }
        else
        {
                return -1;
        }
    }

   return success;

}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to telnet to the 54.x.x.x ip without using your application? Same behavior?

Comment: no, Manual putty application work fine

Comment: 'Non-blocking with a timeout' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 28):

Based on your information:

- You are trying to do a `connect()` to `54.x.x.x`
- The socket is `non-blocking`
- Connection timeout is `60 sec`

First, if you look into your `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h` you'll see the following:

```
#define EINPROGRESS     115     /* Operation now in progress */
```

It means an existing operation on the socket is in progress. Since, you said you are doing a `connect()` call, lets do a [`man connect`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/connect):

```
EINPROGRESS

The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed 
immediately. It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for completion by
selecting the socket for writing. After select(2) indicates
writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the SO_ERROR option at level
SOL_SOCKET to determine whether connect() completed successfully
(SO_ERROR is zero) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual
error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).
```

So, the best guess would be that the TCP 3-way handshake (your `connect()` call to `54.x.x.x` IP address) is taking longer than expected to complete. Since the `connect()` operation is already in progress, any subsequent operation on the socket is resulting into `EINPROGRESS` error code. As suggested in the man page, try to use `select()` or `poll()` to check if your socket is ready to use (to perform `read()` or `write()` calls).

You can pin-point what is preventing your TCP handshake to complete by capturing and analyzing the traffic to/from your own machine and `54.x.x.x`. The best tool to help you with this is called [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org). Good luck.

[image: TCP 3 way handshake]

Comment: I have added my Code above , can u please check is any possible errors ?  the above code work fine in my netwrok , may be because of my network non-block error EINPROGRESS never occure

Comment: @user1340512: Try posting clean and complete version of the code so that one can test.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply , I can't post all code here , But I pasted only the code whhere failure is return . The code work fine in our network (may be because in our network non-block error never happen and conenct always success) . I need to know is if EINPROGRESS errno set is above code work fine or before 60 s the abvoe code can return -1

Answer (score 10):

This seems to be the behaviour of [connect()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/connect):

> If the connection cannot be established immediately and O_NONBLOCK is
>   set for the file descriptor for the socket, connect() shall fail and
>   set errno to [EINPROGRESS], but the connection request shall not be
>   aborted, and the connection shall be established asynchronously.
>   Subsequent calls to connect() for the same socket, before the
>   connection is established, shall fail and set errno to [EALREADY].

Comment: My application is SFTP, user creates many connect to same server with same port 22