# Weird behavior with select for waiting to write in a socket

Tags: c, sockets

I just want to wait after I connect my socket to see if I can write into it.
So I create & connect my socket and use "select" to do the job, unless ... that don't sort out correctly.

here's my code :

```
int SocketToBox(char boxIp[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN], int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in boxAddress;
    int                sock      = -1;

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) == -1) {
        printf("%s : socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) : errno = '%s'.\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        return (-1);
    }

    memset(&boxAddress, 0, sizeof(boxAddress));
    boxAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    boxAddress.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, boxIp, &boxAddress.sin_addr) != 1) {
        printf("%s : inet_pton(AF_INET, boxIp<'%s'>, &boxAddress.sin_addr) : errno = '%s'.\n", __func__, boxIp, strerror(errno));
        close(sock);
        return (-1);
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&boxAddress, sizeof(boxAddress)) == -1) {
        if (errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            printf("%s : connect(sock<%d>, (struct sockaddr *)&boxAddress, sizeof(boxAddress)) : errno = '%s'.\n", __func__, sock, strerror(errno));
            close(sock);
            return (-1);
        }
    }
    return (sock);
}



int main(void)
{
    int    sock;
    fd_set writeFdSet;
    char   *message   = "Hello World !";

    if ((sock = SocketToBox("192.192.192.192", 2000)) == -1) {
        printf("%s : SocketToBox(\"192.192.192.192\", 2000) : callstack.\n", __func__);
        return (1);
    }

    FD_ZERO(&writeFdSet);
    FD_SET(sock, &writeFdSet);

    if (select(sock + 1, NULL, &writeFdSet, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("%s : select(sock<%d> + 1, NULL, &writeFdSet, NULL, NULL) : errno = '%s'.", __func__, sock, strerror(errno));
        return (1);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &writeFdSet)) {
        printf("socket UP.\n");

        if (send(sock, message, strlen(message), MSG_DONTWAIT) == -1) {
            printf("%s : send(sock<%d>, message<'%s'>, strlen(message)<%zu>, MSG_DONTWAIT) : errno '%s'.\n", __func__, sock, message, strlen(message), strerror(errno));
            return (1);
        }
        printf("Message sended.\n");
    } else {
        printf("socket DOWN.\n");
    }

    FD_ZERO(&writeFdSet);
    if (sock == -1) {
        close(sock);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

And my output :

```
socket UP.
main : send(sock<3>, message<'Hello World !'>, strlen(message)<13>, MSG_DONTWAIT) : errno 'Connection timed out'.
```

What did I miss ?
select return 1, and I don't understand that either ! Why 1 and not 0 ?
And why my socket is tagged "writable" by select when a send failed ?
I can ensure you that i can't ping 192.192.192.192.

Comment: I recommend you start by reading [a `select` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html), it should explain both behaviors.

Comment: Thanks ... really. I already read this select man page and I don't understand the behavior.
I will try to turn my question this way : Why a socket, that I purposely connect to nothing, is tagged by select to be writable ?

Comment: `SOCK_NONBLOCK` and `MSG_DONTWAIT` are non-standard (i.e., non-POSIX). What operating-system is this for?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to say so : it's Debian.

Comment: you may want to read the answer at: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204134/tcp-connect-error-115-operation-in-progress-what-is-the-cause` which is about this same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the `select` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html):

> On success, `select()` and `pselect()` return the number of file descriptors contained in the three returned descriptor sets

That's why the `select` function returns `1` for you: It returns with one descriptor set in the sets.

---

For the second problem, also from the manual page:

> A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a corresponding I/O operation (e.g., `read(2)` without blocking, or a sufficiently small `write(2)`).

and

> those in `writefds` will be watched to see if space is available for write (though a large write may still block)

So all `select` will tell you is that there are space available in the descriptors internal buffers, it doesn't say anything about if the data can actually be sent.

Comment: Okay, thanks.
I haven't understand that at all at the first read of man, but it make sense.
The OS just say that he have a buffer ready for writting, not the socket is connected.
Guess I will have to find another way to know if a socket is really connected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because writing to unconnected socket won't block - and this is the only thing select guarantees you.