# Do more iteration at a time python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a blocking for-loop where I try to connect with socket to a server.
I want to make a non-blocking loop because it takes a lot of time, like overlap connections.
Here's my example code:

```
import socket

for _ in range(100):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
        s.connect(('', 4444))
```

Comment: What you're looking for is multithreading.

Comment: take a look at asyncio for I/O operations

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python multiprocessing", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: i know threading, multiprocessing and asyncio but i need an example on my code, if you can. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by MLAlex, it makes sense to use the asyncio library.

What about this, inspired from the [asyncio docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html):

```
import asyncio

async def tcp_echo_client(message):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    print(f'Send: {message!r}')
    writer.write(message.encode())

    await asyncio.sleep(randint(1,3))

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print(f'Received: {data.decode()!r}')

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()

    return data.decode()


async def main():
    requests = [
            tcp_echo_client(f"msg {i}") for i in range(10)
    ]
    echoes = await asyncio.gather(*requests)
    print(echoes)


asyncio.run(main())
```

e.g. coupled with this echo server (which takes three seconds to echo back one message):

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    print(f"Send: {message!r}")
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the connection")
    writer.close()

async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(
        handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving on {addr}')

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

produces:

```
Send: 'msg 0'
Send: 'msg 1'
Send: 'msg 2'
Send: 'msg 3'
Send: 'msg 4'
Send: 'msg 5'
Send: 'msg 6'
Send: 'msg 7'
Send: 'msg 8'
Send: 'msg 9'
Received: 'msg 0'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 1'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 2'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 3'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 4'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 5'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 6'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 7'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 8'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 9'
Close the connection
['msg 0', 'msg 1', 'msg 2', 'msg 3', 'msg 4', 'msg 5', 'msg 6', 'msg 7', 'msg 8', 'msg 9']
```

in three seconds or so, i.e. the time it takes to satisfy one request only

```
real    0m3,169s
user    0m0,044s
sys     0m0,084s
```

If we introduce some variance in the time it takes the server to reply, we can see the clients receiving results out of order.
e.g. on line 10:

```
await asyncio.sleep(randint(3,4))
```

then the output of the client becomes:

```
(tih1) SO $ time python aio_cnx.py 
Send: 'msg 0'
Send: 'msg 1'
Send: 'msg 2'
Send: 'msg 3'
Send: 'msg 4'
Send: 'msg 5'
Send: 'msg 6'
Send: 'msg 7'
Send: 'msg 8'
Send: 'msg 9'
Received: 'msg 1'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 2'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 3'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 7'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 8'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 9'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 0'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 4'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 5'
Close the connection
Received: 'msg 6'
Close the connection
['msg 0', 'msg 1', 'msg 2', 'msg 3', 'msg 4', 'msg 5', 'msg 6', 'msg 7', 'msg 8', 'msg 9']

real    0m4,135s
user    0m0,059s
sys     0m0,013s
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comment and code, but my code is more complicated than the example i put in the question, and yours will never work with mine. Sorry

Comment: I see. No problem, this is one way to do it, based on the info provided. If it doesn't fit your constraints it might help others as an answer

Comment: yeah, it's becouse I don't want to make heavy my code or upset it totally. I'm sorry again

Answer (score 1):

give a try on selectors, base on the fact that you are trying to do non-block I/O on sockets

my sample code to play around localhost ssh server
with 10 concurrent  connection attempts

```
import sys
import socket
import selectors

sel = selectors.EpollSelector()

def read_conn(obj, mask):
    try:
        data = obj.recv(1024)
        if data :
            print(data.decode("utf-8"))
        else:
            sel.unregister(obj)
            obj.close()
    except Exception as  ex:
        print( ex )
        sel.unregister(obj)
        obj.close()


def write_conn(obj, mask):
    msg=b"flooding\n\n"
    obj.send(msg)
    sel.unregister(obj)
    sel.register(obj,selectors.EVENT_READ,read_conn)
    return

for i in range(10) :

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    addr = ('127.0.0.1',22)
    try:
        sock.connect(addr)
        print(f"tried {i}")
        sock.setblocking(False)
        sel.register(sock,selectors.EVENT_WRITE, write_conn)
    except socket.error as ex:
        print("fail to connect error {}".format(ex))
        sys.exit(1)

while True:
    events = sel.select(1)
    if len(events) == 0:
        print("all done")
        break
    for key, mask in events:
        callback= key.data
        callback(key.fileobj,mask)
```

on my vm its output

```
tried 0
tried 1
tried 2
tried 3
tried 4
tried 5
tried 6
tried 7
tried 8
tried 9
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Protocol mismatch.

SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Protocol mismatch.

SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Protocol mismatch.

[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Protocol mismatch.

  cut out duplicate outputs

all done
```

Comment: i did the non-block setting  after socket.connect(), because connect() raises exceptions easily in non-block mode, error no 115

Comment: if your want to do  non-block connect
replace the sock.connect() call with sock.connect_ex() 
and move sock.setblocking() before sock.connect_ex()

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204134/tcp-connect-error-115-operation-in-progress-what-is-the-cause