# How to make a random sample from the internet?

Tags: python, random

I am trying to get random sample of internet pages, I don't want to scrap google search results for various reasons. Here is how I have tried it to do;

```
import socket
from random import randint

def doesitserveawebpage(ip):
    ip=str(ip)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((ip, 80))
        s.shutdown(2)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def givemerandomwebsite():
    adrformat = "%d.%d.%d.%d"
    while True:
        adr = adrformat % tuple(randint(0,255) for _ in range(4))
        try:
            print "Tring %s" % adr
            name = socket.gethostbyaddr(adr)
            if (doesitserveawebpage(adr)):
                return name
            else:
                continue
        except socket.herror:
            continue
```

Well, it doesn't work. First, it works too slow. Second, it gives me addreses that don't serve web pages. Is there anyway I can make this code better, or would you suggest another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Modern web servers (HTTP 1.1) *need* a hostname, as they will serve *many* different sites on the same IP address. Your approach is not going to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasons you want the sample? It might help narrow down the problem domain a bit (for example to a narrower initial population than the internet).

Comment: Also, by poking at random IP addresses around the world, you are more likely to run into machines that *do not* host websites than machines that do.

Comment: You may find [this paper](http://irl.cs.tamu.edu/people/hsin-tsang/papers/tweb2009.pdf) useful—it shows how to build a web crawler that will grab a significant portion of the internet, while saturating your inbound connection.

Comment: Your sample will be always biased by the discovery method you use, so I believe you need to define n which ways you accept your sample to be biased. For example: even if connecting to random IP addresses worked, pages sharing IP addresses with others would be less likely to be hit than pages using an IP address exclusively. You could try connecting to random domain names, but then some domain names will be more likely to be hit than others. You could try following random links, then pages with more incoming links would be more likely to be hit.

Comment: Your task has so many complications unrelated to programming, that I believe it belongs to http://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead (but only after it is rephrased to clarify what you really need).

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumption that most HTTP servers runs on a host with domain name (e.g. not just an IP address), you can further verify your random IP addresses by doing a DNS lookup, e.g. dig.

Also, you should not allow your algorithm to create a random IP that is part of the private IP ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

1. Your code works slow because it blocks execution until (a) the host is looked up (b) you could establish a connection or worse your connection times out, which could take a while.
2. Your code gives hostnames that do not serve web pages for several possible reasons: (a) Using port 80 to serve web pages is merely a convention. I could serve anything I'd desire on port 80 from my server. (b) The top-level domain could be configured not to serve anything. E.g. only subdomains or certain URLs will yield a valid http response. (c) several other reasons I am unaware of.

To solve 1. you have to go asynchronous. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205863/how-can-i-get-non-blocking-socket-connects) will help.

I think, 2. can't be solved. If it could, [size estimates of the web](http://www.worldwidewebsize.com) would be much more reliable.

Concerning better strategies, the comments to your question still apply.

Furthermore, there could be web servers having only IPv6 addresses assigned to them, so your sample is skewed in yet another way. This is not of much practical relevance today, but things change rapidly nowadays.